# trying to convert json to a dataframe

Tags: json, list, dictionary, nested

```
 {'document_tone': 
        {'tones': 
       [{'score': 0.526516, 'tone_id': 'fear', 'tone_name': 'Fear'},
       {'score': 0.78945, 'tone_id': 'confident', 'tone_name': 'Confident'}]},
    
     'sentences_tone': 
      [{'sentence_id': 0,
       'text': 'Messi is the real star of Barca, Messi is better than Neymar and Ronaldo.',
       'tones': [{'score': 0.604674, 'tone_id': 'joy', 'tone_name': 'Joy'}]},
      {'sentence_id': 1,
       'text': 'Corona virus is a huge threat, it s a pandemic #',
       'tones': [{'score': 0.836565, 'tone_id': 'fear', 'tone_name': 'Fear'}]}]}
```

expecting a dataframe with tones and text for "sentences_tone"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to have two seperate DFs you can use the following code

```
import pandas as pd
data={'document_tone': 
{'tones': 
[{'score': 0.526516, 'tone_id': 'fear', 'tone_name': 'Fear'},
{'score': 0.78945, 'tone_id': 'confident', 'tone_name': 'Confident'}]},
'sentences_tone': 
[{'sentence_id': 0,
'text': 'Messi is the real star of Barca, Messi is better than Neymar and Ronaldo.',
'tones': [{'score': 0.604674, 'tone_id': 'joy', 'tone_name': 'Joy'}]},
{'sentence_id': 1,
'text': 'Corona virus is a huge threat, it s a pandemic #',
'tones': [{'score': 0.836565, 'tone_id': 'fear', 'tone_name': 'Fear'}]}]}

tones = pd.DataFrame(a["document_tone"]["tones"])
sentences_tone = pd.DataFrame(a["sentences_tone"])
sentences_tone = pd.concat([sentences_tone.drop('tones', axis=1), pd.DataFrame(sentences_tone['tones'].explode().tolist())], axis=1)
```

Tones is the first DataFrame, sentences_tone the secound one.